# How strict is Skyrim's 'Mage Armor' perk on the armor restriction?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I'm looking here at the Mage Armor perk, and it supposedly doubles Stoneflesh's effectiveness if 'not wearing armor.'

I just picked up a mask called 'Morokei' that increases Magika regen 100%. Only problem, it's classified as light armor.

Will this destroy the effects of Mage Armor?

Comment: Anything that is light armor or better negates this perk.

Answer (score 9):

You will no longer get the benefits of mage armor if you wear any kind of armor.

The only exception to this rule is shields. Wielding a shield does not negate the effects. You receive the benefit of this perk along with the usual benefits of a shield.

Comment: Aw, that's a shame. Such a useful mask. I can't decide now between getting the perk or spending my perks elsewhere. Because that extra 100% regen is real nice.

Comment: Actually mage armor is totally useless vs legendary smithed gear, unless you're roleplaying a robe and wizard hat kind of mage.

Comment: People who do not find magicka regen to be not useful just have bad magicka regen, I have found. Having good cost reduction is nice, but having good magicka regen is also nice. There are more than one way of building a viable character.

Comment: Just want to add to what others have stated - If you want to play a mage that only wears cloth items (no light armor or better) then the mage armor perk is invaluable. I love it and have never regretted taking it. I've got a circlet that gives me +60 magicka and I find it much more useful than the +100 magicka regen from the mask. However, this doesn't mean you should throw the mask out and never use it, because there may be scenarios where it can be useful (ie - when you don't necessarily need to worry about armor).

Comment: @Jagd that's kind of what I thought. If I'm battling with other mages, I put on the mask. IMO, it's all about regen when battling other mages. If you've got someone pummeling you with shock and wiping out your magika, the faster you can gather enough to throw a fireball while hiding behind a pole the better.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all masks destroy this perk effect as long as they are in use because all of them are considered as armor. To get the bonus of Mage Armor you can only use items that are considered as clothes. However, shields are an exception (you can use a shield and have the bonus of Mage Armor).

Answer (score 3):

1) Morokei is a Daedra artifact/Dragon mask and all Dragon masks fall under the "circlet" category. This means that they will in fact work Mage armor, and, it should be equip-able with the archmage robes for what its worth as well. Haven't tested myself though. Also, if it wasn't clear, you can use the heavy armor dragon mask as well I think. (source - http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alteration)

2) Mage Armor works with any circlet and shield (mentioned in other comments - just confirming it works)

3) Nothing "destroys" the effect of mage armor from my understanding. If you have no cloths, cast mage armor, and then equip heavy armor, the full armor bonus + heavy armor will be applied. However, if you re-cast while its on, then the buff will go away.